# Is there an efficient algorithm to decide whether a particular subset of given integers exists?

Tags: algorithms, integers, discrete-optimization

let $ k+1 $ positive integers $ A>a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots \ge a_k $ be given. A subset $ M \subseteq \lbrace 1,\ldots,k \rbrace $ is called *good*, if

(i) $ \sum_{m \in M} a_m \ge A $

(ii) Property (i) does not hold for any proper subset $ M' \subset M $.

Is there an efficient way (i.e., for instance of order $ k^d $ for some small $ d \in \mathbb{N} $) to decide whether there exists a good set $ M $ with $ |M| \ge 3 $ or not?

Comment: If $a_1 +a_2 < A$ then the problem is easy.  Can you prove that?  A general efficient algorithm can be developed using that type of observation. It may also help to define $m$ as the smallest index such that $\sum_{i=m}^k a_i < A$.

Comment: PS:  The algorithm I have in mind has complexity $O(k^2)$.  I would be surprised if you can find a faster one than this, please comment to me if you find one as I would like to see it.

Comment: @orlp Usually to prove that something is "hard", you show that it can be used to solve problems that are *already known* to be hard. Your argument is in reverse, it says that if we have a solution to the hard problem of finding a subset that sum within a range, then we can solve the current problem. In fact, the current problem may be easier than the hard problem.

Comment: @Michael I'm pretty sure you were talking to someone else, but I'll assume my answer is correct, and that it could interest you.

Comment: did you try anything? a non efficient way? I think this problem is very, very simple.

Comment: why not start with the full set and remove elements until you can't?

Comment: @michael: I know that $ a_1+a_2 <A $ is sufficient to answer the question.. Either we then have $ \sum a_i < A $ (so the answer would be "No"), or if $ \sum a_i \ge A $ then there has to be at least one good set. But this one cannot be of cardinality $ 2 $ due to $ a_1+a_2 < A $ implies $ a_i  + a_j <A $ for all $ i \neq j $. (so the answer would be "Yes")

Comment: @miracle173: Starting with the full set and removing elements as long as it is possible may lead to a decision if we end up with a good set of cardinality $ \ge 3 $. If we end upt with a set of cardinality $ 2 $, then we don't have any information. (I think the counterexample given in the next answer is also helpful to see this.)

Comment: @Phil thank you. Now I see it is not so trivial-

Comment: @Phil : Yes, that argument about the case $a_1+a_2 <A$ looks good. So then, assuming $a_1+a_2 \geq A$, what happens if $a_2 + a_3 < A$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what happens if $ a_1+a_2 \ge A $ and $ a_2+a_3 < A $.Could you explain your (whole) idea in a separate answer?

Comment: @Phil : I gave some more details in my last comment to miracle173.  Is that sufficient? I could provide more details if desired but I don't want to compete with miracle's answer and I was intending to not give an answer entirely away since that seems like "doing someone's homework for them."  Of course, miracle's answer seems relatively complete so an answer now is completely out there.  I am still interested to know if we can beat $O(k^2)$.

Comment: Yes, I saw this. I think I did not get the idea of testing $ a_i+a_{i+1}<A $ for all $ i \le m $ in advance. As written above, I understand the implications of the first test $ a_1+a_2<A $. But could you perhaps explain the next step? So, assuming $ a_1+a_2 \ge A $: what happens in the cases $ a_2+a_3 < A $ and $ a_2+a_3 \ge A $?

Comment: @Michael I realize this is rather brazen of me after I failed miserably in my previous attempt, but I think I may have an $O(k\log k)$ solution. Could you have a look? I posted it as a separate answer because it differs quite a bit from my initial approach.

Comment: @Michael if the a_i are already sorted then the algorithm can be implemented that it needs O(n) time.

Comment: @Phil I added the description of a linear algorithm and its Pyython implementation to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary/outline

This is my second proposal. My initial answer was proven false, and I plan on removing it by next week. Because this is quite different, I decided to post a new answer instead of editing my previous one. If that is contrary to the network policy, I apologize in advance.

This is rather lengthy, so a tl;dr: I claim there's a way to solve the problem with a $k\log k$ test. **[EDIT]: I now believe this can be done in $\mathcal O(k)$.** Originally, the $k\log k$ cost came from a sort operation that can in fact be simplified. More details in the new section dedicated to the complexity, after I explain the principle of the method.

I introduce a characterization of the desired subset, and then explain the principle
of the algorithm I derive from that characterization. Because that algorithm fails if we use its naive introduction, I then explain how to deal with the issue.
Finally I provide some pseudo-code.

---

### Necessary property

**Claim**: There exists a *good* subset $M$ with $\lvert M\rvert\ge 3$ if and only if
there are two indices $i$ and $j$ such that:

- $i<j<k$
- $a_i+a_j <A$, and
- $a_i+a_j+\sum_{l=j+1}^ka_l\ge A$

Proof: We proceed by double implication.

Let $M$ a *good* subset with cardinality at least 3. Let $i<j$ be its two minimum indices. By condition (ii), $a_i+a_j< A$.
By condition (i) we have
$a_i+a_j+\sum_{l=j+1}^ka_l \ge \sum_{l\in M}a_l \ge A$.
Therefore the two minimum indices from $M$ satisfy the property.

Conversely, suppose there are two indices $i$ and $j$ that satisfy the property. Initialize $M=\{i,j\}$.
Loop over index $l$, starting from the value $j+1$ up to $k$. Add index $l$ to $M$ if the sum over elements in $M$ is strictly smaller than $A$. If the sum is greater than or equal to $A$, we can stop.
Because we add elements that are smaller and smaller, the resulting $M$ will be *good*. In other words when we finally reach a subset $M$ whose sum is greater than (or equal to) $A$, condition (ii) will also be fulfilled.

---

### Principle of the method

This equivalence suggests that we can loop over possible indices $j$, that is $2\le j\le k-1$, and try to look for some index $i$ that fits the criterion.
That is, given some index $j$, can we find an index $i$ such that:

- $i<j$
- $A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l\le a_i< A-a_j$

Note that $i<j$ implies $a_i\ge a_j$, thus $a_i$ must also fulfill that inequality.
Ideally, I would like to define
$b^-_j=\max\{ a_j;\ A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l\}$ and $b^+_j=A-a_j$, then say that
it suffices to find some index $i$ such that
$b^-_j\le a_i<b^+_j$.
That however does not work because $a_i\ge a_j$ does not imply $i<j$.
Indeed,
some of the values $a_{i/j}$ can be repeated.

[EDIT]: As someone pointed out in the comments, this problem can also be expressed as finding
$i$ with $b^-_j\le a_i<b^+_j$, but then you realize that $i=j$.

**IF** we actually had equivalence, we could achieve a test for a *good*
subset $M$, $\lvert M\rvert\ge 3$ by using a sorted list.
First we drop any interval $[b^-_j,b^+_j)$ that is empty, in other words if
$b^+_j\le b^-_j$, we can forget about that particular $j$ candidate.
Then we sort every (remaining) $b^-_j$, $b^+_j$ and $a_i$,
with the convention that for equal values,
$b^-_j$ is smaller than $a_i$,
and $a_i$ is smaller than $b^+_j$.
We could go over the sorted list and:

- When we pop out some $b^-_j$, the corresponding interval is declared "open".
- When we pop out some $b^+_j$, the corresponding interval is declared "closed".
- When we pop out some $a_i$, two cases arise. If some interval is "open", then we have just found a good pair $i,j$. If no interval is "open", then we just continue with other values.

---

### On the complexity

**[EDIT]: I changed my complexity claim to linear (previously $k\log k$).**

In general, sorting arbitrary lists is a $k\log k$ process, so the procedure above would have $k\log k$ complexity. However, here the lists are not arbitrary.
We actually have to merge lists that are already sorted, and that can be done in linear time.

Indeed, the $a_i$ are decreasing, and thus $b^+_j=A-a_j$ is increasing.
Because the $a_i$'s are positive integers, the sum $\sum_{l=j}^ka_l$ is strictly decreasing, and thus $A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l$ is strictly increasing.
It follows that $b^-_j$ is a maximum between two monotonous sequences and can also easily be merged.

These remarks also hold with the modified values $\hat a_i$, $\hat b_j^-$ and
$\hat b^+_j$ that I introduce below.

---

### Solving the issue of repeated values ($i\ge j$, $a_i\le a_j$).

For my proposed method to work, we need to obtain a way to have an equivalence between $i<j$ and $a_i>a_j$.
Because we are working with integers, this can be achieved by defining new values $\hat a_i$ that are not necessarily integers.

If $a_i$ appears only once, we let $\hat a_i=a_i$.

If the value $a_i$ appears several times, say $n$ times at indices
$i_1<\ldots<i_m<\ldots<i_n$. Then we let $\hat a_{i_m}=a_i+\frac{m-1}n$.
We thus obtain non-integer values with
$$a_i+1 > \hat a_{i_1} >\ldots> \hat a_{i_m} >\ldots> \hat a_{i_n}=a_i$$
It follows that $i<j$ is equivalent to $\hat a_i>\hat a_j$.

[EDIT]: Tl;dr small change to the definition of $\hat b^-_j$ so that my claim 2 can have a correct proof. That change requires a new notation $n_i$.

For an index $i$, let $n_i$ be the number of times the value $a_i$ appears in the original list (possibly $n_i=1$). Notice that $\frac 1{n_i}$ is the distance between consecutive values $\hat a_{i_m}$ and $\hat a_{i_{m+1}}$, when $n_i\ge 2$.

Then we define
$\hat b^-_j=\max\{ \hat a_j+\frac 1{2n_j};\ A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l\}$ and 
$\hat b^+_j=A-a_j$.
Observe that regardless of the value of $n_j$, we have
$$\hat a_{j-1} > \hat a_j+\frac 1{2n_j} > \hat a_{j} $$

[EDIT]: Claim 2 remains unchanged, but its proof has changed to reflect the change in definition.

**Claim 2**:
We have $\hat b^-_j\le \hat a_i< \hat b_j^+$ if and only if

- $i<j$, and
- $A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l\le a_i< A-a_j$

Proof: Assume first that $\hat b^-_j\le \hat a_i< \hat b^+_j$.
By definition of the various terms we have
$$
\hat a_i\ge\hat b^-_j\ge\hat a_j+\frac 1{2n_j}>\hat a_j
$$
The part that actually interests us is $\hat a_i>\hat a_j$, since it implies $i<j$. We get our first condition.
For the second condition, notice that because
$A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l$ is an integer we can use the floor function and preserve inequalities:
\begin{align*}
\hat b^-_j\le \hat a_i< \hat b^+_j
&\implies A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l\le \hat a_i< A-a_j\\
&\implies \left\lfloor A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l\right\rfloor\le \lfloor\hat a_i\rfloor< A-a_j\\
&\implies A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l\le a_i< A-a_j
\end{align*}
Thus, the two conditions are verified.

Conversely, suppose that $i<j$ and
$A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l\le a_i< A-a_j$.
Because 
$$A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l\le a_i\le \hat a_i< a_i+1\le A-a_j=\hat b^+_j$$
we have 
$$A-\sum_{l=j}^ka_l\le \hat a_i<\hat b^+_j$$
Because $i<j$ we know that 
$$
\hat a_i\ge \hat a_{j-1}>\hat a_j +\frac 1{2n_j}
$$
Combined with the above, we deduce 
$\hat b^-_j\le \hat a_i$. The two conditions thus imply
$\hat b^-_j\le \hat a_i<\hat b^+_j$, which concludes the proof.

---

### Pseudo-code

In this pseudo-code, `b+_j` denotes $\hat b^+_j$, likewise `b-_j` is for $\hat b^-_j$. Also, `a_i` actually denotes $\hat a_i$.
Computing the values of $\hat a_i$ can be done in linear time wrt $k$.

```
Compute the various b+_j and b-_j          //linear wrt k
Discard any pair b-_j/b+_j if b+_j <= b-j  //forget about intervals with no solution

Sort the b+_j, b-_j and a_i in a list L    //k log k

state = [0,...,0]                          //array of k values for interval status: 0=closed, 1=open
open_flag = 0                              //counter value indicating if some interval is open


for x in L:

    if x is an element of type b-_j:        //open interval j
        state[j] = 1
        open_flag += 1
    end if

    if x is an element of type b+_j:        //close interval j
        state[j] = 0
        open_flag -= 1
    end if

    if x is an element of type a_i:         //check if an interval is open
        if open_flag > 0:
            return True or find a good pair i,j using the "state" array
        end if
    end if

end for             //this loop was linear wrt the size of L, thus linear wrt k


return False        //if we reach this point, we never found a good pair
```

Note that if we do not care about finding a *good* subset, and only about its existence, we do not need to care about the state array.

Comment: This looks like a great idea. I read the first part (the claim is good) and the "principle of method."  What happens if $b_j^- > b_j^+$? [I guess you can just remove those from consideration.]

Comment: Sorting the $a_i$ and $b_i^+, b_i^-$ all together is very clever.  Removing those instances that $b_j^->b_j^+$, it seems the difficulty is ensuring that if you find an $a_i$ in some open interval, it is _not_ the open interval of $i$.  I don't think this is an issue if, for example, the $a_i$ are distinct integers but $A$ is noninteger. This difficulty seems minor and likely can be taken care of (perhaps by the way you proposed with $\tilde{a}_i$, I did not read that part).  So I give +1 for an $O(k\log(k))$ method.

Comment: This idea looks good. But how do you decide whether a given element of the list is of type $ b^{-} $, $ a_i $ or $ b^{+} $? Moreover, why do we need both (the state-vector and the openflag-indicator) to decide if an interval is open? Or do we just need the state vector if we would be more accurate than just mentioning the existence of a good set?

Comment: @Michael Yes, I just assumed we could remove the instances when $b^-_j\ge b^+_j$. I'll integrate this remark. In my head, the difficulty lied somewhere else and I didn't notice the problem of $a_i$ being in the interval defined by $i$. The current version does not solve this problem, but it can be solved by the implementation, or modifying my method a little bit. In particular, the $\hat a_i$ I proposed are all distinct, so as you said, it should be overall okay. I'll modify this.

Comment: @Michael I also just realized, but maybe the sorting can be done more efficiently, because we basically merge 3 sorted lists. The $a_i$'s are decreasing, the $b^+_j$ are increasing, and $b^-_j$ is a max between an increasing and a decreasing sequence. When merging sorted lists, I think there's a way to do it linearly in the size of the output list, which would bring us down to linear complexity wrt $k$.

Comment: @Phil For your first remark, deciding the type would be dependent on the implementation. You could create custom data-types/class objects and literally check that.
You can also use tuple values: `(<actual_value>, <type_indicator>)`. Use the `<actual_value>` to sort the elements, and `<type_indicator>` could be an integer to distinguish between $a_i$, $b^-_j$ and $b^+_j$. In fact, `<type_indicator>`would play a role in the sort/comparison, when some values are equal.

Comment: @Phil For the other remark, that is half-correct. If we only care about existence, I thought that the `open_flag` would be sufficient, but a comment from Michael made me realize this is currently slightly insufficient. There's is as of now, a little mistake in the proof of my second claim. I'm going to modify it. The decisive advantage of the `state` vector is that you can find the actual values of $i,j$, if that value can be derived from the element in the list `L`. One way to do that is to use a 3-tuple instead of the 2-tuple I gave you in my last comment.

Answer (score 2):

1. If a good subsequence of $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ exists  then the sum of all $a_i$ must be greater or equal than $A.$ So in the following we assume that the sum of the sequence is greater or equal than $A.$
2. If the sum of the sequence is greater or equal than $A$ then in linear time a good subsequence can be calculated. Simply scan through the elements of the sequence and remove an element from the sequence if the remaining elements sum up to a value greater or equal to $A$. If you have scanned through the whole sequence the remaining elements sum to a value greater or equal to $A$ but if you remove one of these elements the sum of the remaining will be less than $A.$ The sequence you find with this algorithm may have 1, 2, 3 or more elements. If you end with 1 or 2 elements you don't know if a good sequence exists with 3 or more elements exists.
3. If the sum of each pair of elements (with different indexes) of a sequence is less than $A$ than  the algorithm described at 2 will find a good sequence with  3 or more elements in linear time because it cannot end with a one or two elements.
4. If $s_3$ is a good subsequence with three or more elements then it cannot have two elements that sum up to a value greater or equal than $A.$
5. If $s_1$ is a subsequence of $s$ and $s_2$ is a subsequence of $s_1$ and therefore a subsequence of $s$ than *$s_2$ is good with respect to $A$ and $s$* if and only if *$s_2$ is good with respect to $s_1$ and $A.$*
6. Define $ss(s,i,A)$ as the subsequence of a sequence $s$ such that $a_k$ is in this subsequence either if $k=i$ or  if $i \lt k$ and $a_i+a_k<A.$
7. If $s_2$ is a good subsequence of a sequence  $s$ with respect to $A$ and $a_i$ is its largest element then $s_2$  is a good subsequence of $ss(s,i,A)$ with respect to $A$. A good subsequence of $ss(s,i,A)$ can be found in linear time as described in 3. A good subsequence of $ss(s,i,A)$ with respect to $A$ must have three or more elements.
8. for all indexes $i$ of $s$ check if there is a good subsequence in $ss(s,i,A)$. If not, then there is not such a subsequence. If yes, you have found one.

**Example1**

If $s$ is the sequence $8,8,7,6,1,1$ and $A=9$ this works in the following way:
we investigate
$$ss(s,1,9)=8$$
$$ss(s,3,9)=7,1,1$$
$$ss(s,4,9)=6,1,1$$
$$ss(s,5,9)=1,1$$

The first two have less than 3 elements and the third and the following one  does not sum up to 9 or higher. So there is no good subsquence.

**Example2**

If $s$ is the sequence $8,8,7,6,2,2,1,1$ and $A=9$ this works in the following way:
we investigate
$$ss(s,1,9)=8$$
$$ss(s,3,9)=7,1,1$$
$$ss(s,4,9)=6,2,2,1,1$$
$$ss(s,5,9)=2,2,1,1$$
$$ss(s,7,9)=1,1$$

Only the third one is of interest. We scan through $6,2,2,1,1$ from the beginning. We cannot drop $6$ but the first $2$ and the first $1$ and end with the good subsequence $6,2,1$

---

From this we construct the following algorithm that needs $O(k)$ time.

## Input

All numbers are integer. We have given $k$ such that
$$k \ge 3 \tag{1}$$
a finite sorted sequence $a_1,\ldots, a_k$, so
$$a_1\ge a_2\ge\ldots\ge a_k \gt 0 \tag{2}$$
and a number $A$ such that
$$A \gt a_1$$

## Decision Algorithm

### Initialization

#### Initialize $u$

we set
\begin{align}
&u:=1\\
&\text{while }(a_u+a_{k-1}\ge A) \text{ and } (u\lt k-2) \\
&\qquad u:=u+1 \\
\end{align}
If now $a_u+a_{k-1}<A$ then there exists no $v$ such that $a_u+a_v\ge A$ and therefore there exists no good subset with at least $3$ elements. The algorithm will terminate.

Otherwise it continues:

#### Initialize $v$

\begin{align}
&\text{tailsum}:=a_{k-1}+a_k\\
&v:=k-1\\
&\text{while }(u \lt v-1) \text{ and }a_u+a_{v-1} \lt A\\
&\qquad v:=v-1\\
&\qquad \text{tailsum}:=\text{tailsum}+a_{v}\\
\end{align}

*loop invariant*
$$\text{tailsum}=\sum_{t=v}^{k}a_t$$

### Loop

\begin{align}
&\text{while }(u\lt v-1) \text{ and }  (a_u+\text{tailsum} \lt A)\\
&\qquad  u:=u+1\\
&\qquad\text{while } (u \lt v-1) \text{ and } (a_u+a_{v-1} \lt A)\\
&\qquad\qquad v:=v-1\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{tailsum}:=\text{tailsum}+a_v\\
\end{align}

Note tha $v$ ts decremented but never incremented in this loop. It can only be decremente $k$ times. So this block is executed in $O(k)$ time.

### Decision

If we have now $$a_u+\text{tailsum}\lt A$$ then $u=v-1$. We haven't found a pair (u,v) such that
$$a_u+\sum_{t=v}^k a_t<A$$
until now and we will not find one when we further decrease $u$ because this will decrease $v$, too, and therefore decrease the sum $a_u+\sum_{t=v}^k a_t.$ So no good set with three or more elements will exist and the algorithm will terminate here.

If  the loop terminates with $a_u+\text{tailsum}\ge A$ then 
$${u, v, v+1, \ldots, k}$$ will have a good subset and this will have $3$ or more elements.

### Construction of the good set

\begin{align}
&\text{if } \text{tailsum} \lt A  \text{ then}\\
&\qquad G:=\{u\}\\
&\qquad\text{sum}:=a_u+\text{tailsum}\\
&\text{else}\\
&\qquad G:=\{\}\\
&\qquad\text{sum}:=\text{tailsum}\\
&t=v\\
&\text{while } (t<=k)\\
&\qquad \text{if } \text{sum} - a_t \lt A  \text{ then}\\
&\qquad\qquad G:=G\cup \{t\}\\
&\qquad\text{else}\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{sum}:=\text{sum}-a_t\\
&\qquad t=t+1\\
\end{align}

*loop invariants:* $$\sum_{t\in G}a_t+\sum_{t=v}^k a_t=\text{sum}$$
$$\sum_{t\in G}a_t+\sum_{t=v}^k a_t \ge A$$
$$\sum_{t\in G\setminus \{r\}}a_t+\sum_{t=v}^k a_t \lt A,\; \forall r \in G$$

---

```
def find_good(a):
  A=a[0]  # python lists start with index 0
  k=len(a)-1
  if k<3:
    return(None)
  u=1
  ## Initialize u
  while(a[u]+a[k-1]>=A) and (u<k-2):
    u=u+1
  if a[u]+a[k-1]>=A:
    return(None)

  ## Initialize v
  v=k-1
  tailsum=a[k-1]+a[k]
  while(a[u]+a[v-1]<A) and (u<v-1):
    v=v-1
    tailsum=tailsum+a[v]

  # loop
  while((u<v-1) and (a[u]+tailsum<A)):
    u=u+1 
    while((u<v-1) and (a[u]+a[v-1]<A)):
      v=v-1
      tailsum=tailsum+a[v]

  # decision
  if ((a[u]+tailsum)<A):
    # no solution exists
    return(None)

  # construction of a goot set:
  if (tailsum<A):
    G=[u]
    sum=a[u]+tailsum
  else:
    G=[]
    sum=0
  t=v
  while (t<=k):
    if sum-a[t]<A:
      G.append(t)
    else:
      sum=sum-a[t]
    t=t+1

  #prepare return value
  H=[a[k] for k in G] # H is a[g1], a[g2],...
  return(G, H)
```

Here is a link to the program: https://repl.it/@miracle173/findgood2

Comment: This looks good (again an $O(k^2)$ algorithm).  The main idea here seems to be "If there exists a good set of size 3 or more, it must start with some largest index $a_i$ and include only other elements $a_j$ such that  $a_j\leq a_i$ and $a_i + a_j < A$."  However, the description seems a bit rough and could be polished...

Comment: Some comments you may want to polish: (0) Some of the points seem irrelevant. (i) You equate “larger than A” with “greater or equal than A” (I know what you mean, but it is distracting). (ii) Point 4 seems to implicitly assume $s_3$ has size larger than 2. (iii) Point 5: What is $s$? (iv) Notation mixes $ss(s,i, A)$ and $ss(s,a_i,A)$.  It also does not specify what  $s$ means (I gather it represents a generic sequence).

Comment: @Michael thank you for your input. When I wrote this I had in my mind that the definition of good includes three or more elements. This is not correct. I tried to correct this.  Which points seem to be irrelevant to you? "again an O(k2) algorithm": Which other $O(k^2)$ algorithms exists?

Comment: Her a link to a Python program (no really written to be presented to the public)  I also calculates some counter examples to the algorithm of  N.Bach https://repl.it/@miracle173/good-sequences

Comment: I was alluding to the $O(k^2)$ algorithm I had in mind in my first two comments on this question: For all $i \in \{1, ..., m-1\}$ (with $m$ defined in my comment) test if  $a_i+a_{i+1} < A$, which can be done in $O(m)$ time for early execution if there is a success.  Else, $a_i + a_{i+1}\geq A$ for all $i \in \{1, …, m-1\}$, and every size-at-least-3 good set must contain _exactly_ one of the numbers in $\{a_1, …, a_{m-1}\}$ and all other numbers in $\{a_m, …, a_k\}$.  So we just test each individual $a_i$ for $i \in \{1, …, m-1\}$ with an $O(k-m)$ test [this yields the quadratic complexity.]

Comment: @miracle173 To be honest, I didn't understand your method until I read michael's comment, and your subsequent revision. If my understanding is correct, I think you made a typo in your first example. Shouldn't $ss(s,7,9)$ be equal to $7,1,1$? A priori, if you kept the first $1$, you should also keep the second $1$? $7,1,1$ is also a *good* sequence with $3$ elements in it, so it is a solution to OP's problem?

Comment: @N.Bach Thank you for your input. I changed the meaning of the 2nd argument of the ss function but forgot to change it in the examples, too. I repaired this. This second argument of ss is now an index ( an element of M) . Before it value a_i, but this was a problem if there where different indexes i and j with a_i=a_j.  I hpe it is clearer now.

Comment: @N.Bach $ss(s,7,9)$ is now $ss(s,3,9)$. This contains of the third element of the sequence s, which is 7, and all elements that are less than $9-7$,so 1 and 1.

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed a quite easy way to answer the decision problem.